# Thread-safe Form.Show

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

I'm writing a Toast that needs to be thread-safe as it's being used to report the status of asynchronous socket input. I've tried to make it thread-safe but the toasts are still locking up.

```
    public static void Show( string message ) {
        Toast toast = new Toast( message );
        toast.ShowAction();
    }

    private delegate void InvokeCallback();

    public void ShowAction() {
        if ( InvokeRequired ) {
            Invoke( new InvokeCallback( ShowAction ) );
        }
        else {
            Show();
        }
    }
```

I want to be able to display them easily like a message box, i.e. `Toast.Show("Status changed");`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is the fact that the `Toast` is being CREATED on another thread. What you'll likely need to do is have a "target" on the main UI thread where you can `Invoke()` the creation AND showing of the `Toast`, keeping all UI on the same thread.

**EDIT**

If you need to be able to keep this on another thread, your only other option is to create another thread with a message loop.

```
Thread t = new Thread();

t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA) // Required for a UI thread
```

As to the implementation of dispatching tasks and messages to this thread, I'll leave that up to you. You'll need to call `Application.Run()` at the start of it in order to start your message loop.

And, as always, you'll have to be sure to `Invoke()` any operations from your Toast (or anything on this thread) that may interact with the main UI thread.

Comment: You can run, on the same thread that creates the form, a message loop around the form. Simply do: Application.Run(form); Note that the form is now in control, so you need the form to close itself when appropriate.

Comment: @lassevk: NO NO NO! Never start a message loop on a thread that you don't start. This could have disastrous consequences!