# How to transfer two forms from project1 to the startup project2?

Tags: c#

The two forms need to run at the same time. 
below showed the code from project1

```
static void Main()
{
    eyeXHost.Start();
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    var f = new cursor();
    f.Show();
    Application.Run(new eye());

    eyeXHost.Dispose();
}
```

Then I need to run `cursor` and `eye` form at the same time at project 2.
I did try out this method below in project2.

```
static void EyeTrackerMode()
{
    eye_tracker = new eyetracker();
    Application.Run(new eye());
    Application.Run(new cursor());                 
}
```

The debug only show one form which is the "eye". Please lend me a hand on this.
Thank you.

Comment: `Form2 form2 = new Form2(); form2.Show(); Application.Run(new eye());` ?

Comment: Hi, Mong Zhu, thanks for your solution, your method is working. However, it does not transfer the function I set in the eye form to the startup project.

Comment: `Application.Run(...)` is synchronous call so every line after that will be called when previous form is closed. Only solutions that i can think of right now is to create two "UI" threads with shared memory and start thease two forms as a separate "Application" or just show 2 forms at once and place one of them into `Application.Run(...)` method.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. But I don't get it how to create two "UI" threads. Can you show some examples?

Comment: [Example of multiple UI threads](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7568376/multiple-ui-threads-winforms)